# XML LINQ: How to select more than one item?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, select

Here's my simplified XML entry:

```
<Product>  
<Name>Red Chair</Name>  
<Price>29.5</Price> 
</Product>
```

I select the Name element like this:

```
select catalogItem.Element("Name").Value
```

How do I select both the Name and the Price? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    from item in xDoc.Descendants("Product")  
    select new 
        { 
          Name = item.Element("Name").Value,
          price = item.Element("Price").Value
        };
```

Comment: You've already cast the element to a `string`.  Attempting to read the `Value` property won't work.  Just leave that part out.

Comment: Though it would be better with the cast alone or the `Value` access, not both.  ;)

Comment: Value already is of type String, so you don't need to cast it.